Solving systems of linear algebraic equations in singular case
I want to solve this system:
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \quad Ax = b, \quad det(A) = 0$
Hence, there are either no solutions or there are infinitely many of them, then I want to find a pseudo-solution:
$x_{*} = A^{+} f$, where $A^{+}$ - pseudoinverse matrix.
My questions:

What is the best way to search for this pseudo-inverse matrix using program code (without using third-party libraries)? I want to implement SVD decomposition of the species:
$A^{+} = V \Sigma^{+} U^{*}$  It sounds laborious but realistic
From the conclusion of the first paragraph, is there any way to find pseudo-solutions without searching for a pseudo-inverse matrix?
Add a little of noise:
$(A + \varphi A)\tilde{x} = f + \gamma f$

Most likely, if the system without noise (the exact system) was singular, then the system with noise will become "bad" in terms of mathematical stability (determinant of matrix A will strive to zero)
For mathematical stability we can use Tikhonov’s regularization:
$(\tilde{A}^T \tilde{A} + \alpha E_n)\tilde{x} = \tilde{A}^T \tilde{f}$
It’s a theory, but I need to do it with code. Is it possible to do it with what I’ve listed? Thanks

Consider asking on overflow as you might have a better answers.
